# How to turn off javascript concatenation in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this nasty error during compression through uglyfier. But it hell of a file, and it's hard to track the reason

Is there a way to turn off concatenation and leaving compression i Rails?

```
Unexpected token: name ($j)
  (in /home/grzegorz/work/navegas/app/assets/javascripts/all.js)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would like your files to *not* be concatened, but still minified, is that it ? Hmm. I don't think there's a 'cool' way to do this, but you would add all your js files names to the list of files to precompile:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'lala.js', ...]
```

And include your separate files when you need them.

Comment: I don't want to loose this concatenation on production, so I'll just track down the file by removing stuff from manifest file and and see when it starts compiling. But I'll accept that, cause it stopped me from searching for non-existing solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a line at the bottom of application.js which includes all js files in the directory.

```
//= require_tree .
```

If you remove this line the files will not be included in the concatenated file. You will have to add in references to them in the html pages where they are used.

Comment: this manifest file is called "all.js" in my project, but I don't have such line in there. Just every single file is explicitly named. But I rather look for a solution to just switch this behavior, not to permanently disable it for my app because it is quite useful on production.